# Swipe gesture in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to add Swipe gesture on my cell. It work fine.but the Problem is when i swipe on first cell but my fifth cell also swipe. I know this indexpath problem. Please help.But i am stuck from few hour.

let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLeftSwipe))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    table.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

```
let swipeLeftd = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLeftSwipes))
swipeLeftd.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
table.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftd)

@objc func handleLeftSwipe(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("rigt called")

    let location = sender.location(in: self.table)
    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! TableViewCell
    print("swipe")
    cell.myView.frame.origin.x = -94
}

@objc func handleLeftSwipes(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("labelSwipedLeft called")
    let location = sender.location(in: self.table)
    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! TableViewCell
    print("swipe")
    cell.myView.frame.origin.x =  80
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "TableViewCell"
    var cell: TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        var nib : Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell",owner: self,options: nil)!
        cell = nib[2] as? TableViewCell
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Can you show your cellforindex?

Comment: @vinbhai4u please check

Comment: try tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: , for: ) in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is reusing your cells. I assume you do not set anything in your `prepareForReuse()`. So, your problem is in line `cell.myView.frame.origin.x =  80`, right? Just set it to default in prepareForReuse or in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

Comment: i have to set two different frame on left swipe and another for right swipe. Will i set all two

Comment: @varun yea, just set all you need for default view of your cells, because when you set it for one specific cell, then during scroll, that cell is being reused, and has it's subviews' frames moved as it was done previously. If I understood you correctly, you do not want them to save their frame origins moved. Therefore, as I stated above, set default views in prepareForReuse()